# Java applications don't start via .apps in Finder

Tags: java, macos, jvm, runtime

I have Mac OS 10.9.3 installed, and when entering `java -version` in the Terminal it shows:

```
java version "1.7.0_55"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)
```

My problem is that applications which use Java don't work when double-clicking on the .app folders. For example, TuxGuitar just does nothing, and Eclipse gives the `No Java virtual machine` error. When launching them with the command

```
open TuxGuitar.app
open Eclipse.app
```

.. they work both. What could be the problem?

Comment: Open the Console app and see if anything happens there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I fixed this by installing a patch from apple at
http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US.

Answer (score 0):

Something is different in the environment of the shell you get in Terminal, compared with the environment Finder.app is running in.  You need to figure out what's different.

A few relevant facts:

- OS X windowed applications do not read your shell startup files like `~/.bash_profile`, so changes you make there to your ${PATH} or ${JAVA_HOME} will not affect windowed applications.
- It used to be the case that OS X windowed applications read `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` but apparently that's no longer true in 10.9 Mavericks; see for example [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688).
- Java on Mac OS X keeps changing, and can be installed and controlled in a variety of ways.  So it's hard to give a general answer; it depends on the history of your system.
- Java Mac GUI applications can place restrictions on which JVM will run them, in `Contents/Info.plist` of the application bundle; look for key `JVMOptions` and in particular at `JVMVersion` within that.

Things to try:

- Open System Preferences and see if you have a Java Control Panel.  If you do, you can use it to select which JVMs are available for running GUI applications, and in what order they will be tried.
- Open a "clean" shell by running `env -i /bin/sh` and then try running `/Applications/TuxGuitar.app/Contents/MacOS/TuxGuitar` inside that shell; you may get a useful error message.
- Use `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` to see a list of JVMs the OS knows about.
- `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7` to see which JVM the OS would choose for an application that needs Java 7.

Comment: I'll give you the bounty for giving the more relevant tips, yet I sitll couldn't find a solution :/

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the bounty, but I'm sorry you're still stuck!  What have you found so far?  What error message do you get when running the executable directly from within a clean shell?

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue after upgrading to Mavericks and I noticed it with `muCommander`.
As I can run the app manually from the command line, I have the following workaround which I am quite happy with:

Create a shell script workflow using [Automator](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2488?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=work-automator):
`Spotlight -> Automator -> Workflow -> "Run Shell Script" -> [shell command]`

Then save the Worflow, but instead of `.workflow`, choose file format `Application`. Now you have an App you can double-click.

---

**Addendum 1:** This is not the answer to your original question as I don't know exactly what the problem is (jbyler's answer might point you in the right directions here).
However, I assumed that your question implies *Can I get double-click to work again?*, and this workaround helped me to do that.

---

**Addendum 2:** I have `JAVA_HOME` set up and the same version installed as you have. This is a screenshot for the Workflow in Automator:

[image: Run Shell Script]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by installing the developer kit.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Open the /Applications/TuxGuitar.app/Contents/MacOS/TuxGuitar with your favourite text editor (it's a shell script) and add "-d32" option to the last line "exec java ...." (position doesn't matter). This will launch java in 32-bit mode. Alternatively you can launch TuxGuitar with "-d32" option (it passes arguments to java) from the terminal.